# Two questions on the principle of indifference

Tags: epistemology, probability

(Sorry if it is not within the format of the site to ask two questions like this, please tell me if I should break it up into two separate questions)

The [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference) states that rational agents should assign equal probabilities to all possible outcomes under consideration.

1. The [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) presents a problem for those who subscribe to the principle of indifference: how can you assign equal probabilities in an unknown probability space? I won't describe Bertrand's original formulation, but I'm  wondering why ["after more than a century the paradox remains unresolved, and continues to stand in refutation of the principle of indifference."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)#Recent_developments) Let us take one version of the problem: the production of a cube of unknown size in a factory (described [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#ClaPro)). My question is: why do we not assign an equal probability to all possible versions of the problem? If we say that the original problem is not well-defined enough to assign probabilities, why can't we simply assign equal probabilities to all the ways the problem could be defined? It seems like this would lead to a nice, final probability. For example, for the cube problem, you could assign a 1/3 probability to a 1D, 2D, and 3D defined space.
2. How can the probability space under consideration ever be defined? As a trivial example, let's say we do not know that a coin has a 50/50 odds of landing heads. According to indifference, we must assign a 50/50 probability regardless, as the probability space is {H, T}. Why must this be the space, though? Let's add to the heads outcome that the 1,000th digit of pi (call this N) is less than 5. The space then becomes {H&(N<5), H&(N>=5), T}. This is just as valid a probability space as any other, but we can trivially make the odds of anything higher using this method. What is the  problem of just adding trivial conditions like these to events that boost their probability?

Comment: Re (1): I would be very surprised if there were only finitely many ways of describing that problem. If there are (countably) infinite ways, then there is no uniform distribution over N, so your proposal seems intractable to me.

Comment: @Kevin Indeed. SEP says "And so on for all of the infinitely many equivalent reformulations of the problem (in terms of the fourth, fifth, … power of the length, and indeed in terms of every non-zero real-valued exponent of the length)." But I don't think this matters, because even if the probability is zero for any exponent, the cumulative probability between (1, 2), for example, is less than (2, 5000) (I think). As you consider more possible dimensions, I think the average cube size tends towards zero, but that's still a specific number.

Comment: I don't think that limit helps you, because you have to define the probability distribution in order to know precisely what limit to take in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin Do you mean the probability distribution over the possible exponents? If so, the principle of indifference would offer a definite probability (or maybe the principle of maximum entropy here, given that there are infinite options).

Comment: Yes, for a start. There is no uniform distribution over the reals (or the positive integers, or any other "reasonable" set of numbers that you might care to range over), so you have to use a *non*-uniform distribution. Which non-uniform distribution are you proposing to use, and how does that comport with the principle of indifference?

Comment: @Kevin SEP says, "When the spaces are countably infinite, the spirit of the classical theory may be upheld by appealing to the information-theoretic principle of maximum entropy, a generalization of the principle of indifference..." Regardless, I wonder if you can come up with a different example. For example, I saw the following argument being made against the principle of indifference: you discover two planets P and Q, and do not know if they contain life. You can either assign a 1/2 probability (extraterrestrial life exists, or not), or 3/4 (both P and Q have life, or only one, or neither).

Comment: SEP also says "We must then impose some further constraint that narrows the field to a smaller family in which there is an assignment of maximum entropy. This constraint has to be imposed from outside as background knowledge, but **there is no general theory of which external constraint should be applied when**" so that really doesn't help.

Comment: @Kevin I see. Do you think my planet problem avoids this?

Comment: Shackel's opinion you quote is not widely shared, what happens in the Bertrand paradox is pretty well understood. The issue is that the description of "random chord", perceived as "intuitively" complete, isn't. The problem of relevant description is ubiquitous in modeling and is not specific to indifference. E.g. in quantum mechanics one gets inequivalent systems with "intuitively" the same Hamiltonian because symmetric operators can have inequivalent self-adjoint extensions. Taking indifference as anything more than a heuristic guideline to be made precise in specific models is a mistake.

Comment: @Conifold What exactly do you mean by heuristic here? Are you talking about something like imprecise probabilities, or simply that it cannot be used here?

Comment: You always have these dichotomies, either it can not be used or it has to be something definitive, if imprecise. It is neither. Thinking about the idea of the "random chord" one discovers that different things can be meant by it for the purposes of indifference. That leads to more precise formulations where probabilities can be assigned, hence "heuristic guideline". Vague instructions for converting classical models into quantum ones work the same way. Which model is suitable, if any, is not dictated by any principles, we find out afterwards by testing it.

Comment: @Conifold I usually mean by those dichotomies that it could be X, could be Y, or could be something else entirely, even if I don't state it explicitly :). I don't know enough about quantum mechanics to make much of an analogy, but wouldn't indifference still place limits on what could be assigned? For Bertrand's paradox, you could say the middle of the circle could be more or less populated with random chords, but it still must be populated. While indifference may not give us the exact density without clarification, it still tells us that there is a non-zero density in any case, correct?

Comment: No. The point of vagueness is that placing limits ahead of time and reasoning about what would happen "one way or another" is counterproductive. Vague guidelines are useful for reasoning from below in a specific context to build something, not circumscribing from above what can be built to still accord with them. Such circumscriptions may be useful to make hidden assumptions explicit, so one can think of novel ways to break them. There is always a problem with lack of imagination.

Comment: @Conifold I see, that makes sense. What do you think of my problem (2) in my question? Is that related to this, in the sense that a little imagination is all that is needed to come up with vastly different probabilities in an undefined probability space?

Comment: The best cure to ignorance is observation, rather than stretching vague principles to put numbers on speculations.

Comment: @Conifold This is a bit more historical, but why do you think it took (relatively) so long to find out that the principle of indifference can lead to contradictions? It seems a very simple problem would suffice: we have three doors, with a prize behind one. You could assign 1/3 to each, or 1/2 to the first, and 1/2 to the other two (it either is the first door, or isn't, we have no evidence either way). Why did it take a somewhat complex example, as in Bertrand's paradox, when this seems to make the same point?

Comment: Because the foundations of probability theory were vague and in flux, and people looked for cases where it could be used to formulate reasonable models, not for those where it couldn't. Bernoulli and Laplace did not even bother to name it or single it out as a "principle". Focus on precision and counterexamples only came in the late 19th century, as did the Bertrand paradox.